# Webapp/app that predicts whether my flight will be canceled

Tags: android, web-apps, ios, weather, travel

Everyday, flights somewhere get canceled because of bad weather. Using [past cancellations data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/19892/database-of-canceled-flights), [past weather data](https://aws.amazon.com/public-datasets/gsod/) and current [weather forecast](https://graphical.weather.gov/xml/rest.php), I feel like cancellation probability could be calculated.

Is there a webapp or mobile app that does this?
Ideally gratis, but non-free solutions welcome too.

Comment: I don't know any apps for this, but just want to clarify, is the reasoning specifically due to weather? Not due to other things like natural disasters, travel restrictions, or emergency situations?

Comment: @AndrewT. Predicting flight cancellations based on other situations such as natural disasters would be wonderful, but it seems harder to implement. In other words, I would be happy enough with apps that base their predictions solely on weather forecasts, but additional prediction power is welcome. Thanks!